# Geth Proof of Authority Implementation

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, proof-of-authority

I have implemented PoA on private blockchain with following genesis.json.

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1515,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "constantinopleBlock": 5,
    "clique": {
      "period": 1,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5c6bf995",
  "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002f980dd10698ff013fadaeed36f64b552de09c4b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "2f980dd10698ff013fadaeed36f64b552de09c4b": {
      "balance": "100000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

I have started geth with following command.

```
geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30311 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner'  --networkid 1515 --gasprice '1' -unlock '0x2f980dd10698ff013fadaeed36f64b552de09c4b' --password node1/password.txt --mine
```

Now the thing that bothers me is that, it keeps on mining blocks (3659 at the time of writing) even if i have not submitted any transaction. Is this the expected behavior from PoA implementation or not. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 2):

Had to change value of period from 1 to 0 and it works as required.

```
"clique": {
      "period": 0,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for every periode(s) the blockchain mines a new block so if u set periode to zero then your blockchain won't mine any block it will not work and save blocks to the blockchain so if you want to make the blockchain work slower set periode to 15s .

Comment: But after every transaction that is submitted, i can see these in the logs INFO [02-27|15:26:45.068] Commit new mining work
INFO [02-27|15:26:45.071] Successfully sealed new block            
INFO [02-27|15:26:45.071]  block reached canonical chain
INFO [02-27|15:26:45.072]  mined potential block
INFO [02-27|15:26:45.071] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions.  Doesn't it mean that it is mining blocks as expected ?

Comment: if u want to verify it then open get console using "geth attach http://localhost:8545" and run eth.blockNumber it will give u the number of the blocks mined in the blockchain

Comment: Yes it does return block number i.e. 36 in my case. I have also verified it by restarting and shutting down my node to check whether data or blockchain persists or not.